# Local database connected (no server needed) to Backend with Java for Desktop application

Tags: java, database, backend, local

I am working on a project in which i am required to have the backend only local with Java.
I finished the fornt end whcih was programmed with framework JavaFxsand and i need to make a backend with a database that doesn't connect to internet not like JDBC whoch is  connected to MySQL with local host
Can anyone help me and suggest any ideas?

i've already tried the JDBC with local connectivity but it always worked with a server which i shouldn't deal with for this project

Comment: Use an embedded DB, say Derby (JavaDB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [embedded database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) is a database engine that works within your app.

You have a choice of database engines written in Java that can be embedded within a Java app. These include:

- [H2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(database))
- [HSQLDB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSQLDB)
- [Derby](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby)

All of these are open source projects.

All three of these can be used as a database server *or* as an embedded database engine.

You still use JDBC to connect to these, whether they are operating in server-mode or in embedded-mode.

---

By the way… You may want to learn about [database migration tools](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) such as [Flyway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or Liquibase.

Comment: which one is the best in term of performance , scalability and when we build the .exe file ?

Comment: @MinariBLIИK All three products are written in pure Java. So you can run them on any platform as part of your app. You will be including the database engine as just another dependency, just another Java library. As for comparison and recommendation, that is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Use sister site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/